# AG-grid Decimal Precision based on the values of the data

Tags: ag-grid

I have some decimal value columns in a grid where I want to have a variable precision based on the values of the decimal. Specifically, decimal places of precision should be 0 if the value is > 9.5, precision should be 1 if the number is between 0.5 and 9.5 & 2 otherwise.
Currently, I am defining the precision in the column definitions like this:

```
"columns": [
    {
        "name": "exposure",
        "type": "DECIMAL",
        "title": "Exposure",
        "precision": 2,
        "width": 77
    },
    {
        "name": "total_risk",
        "type": "DECIMAL",
        "title": "Total Risk",
        "agg_name": "Total Risk",
        "precision": 0,
        "width": 78
    }]
```

Does ag grid provide any functionality like this. I don't see anything in the official documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle displaying values via `valueFormatter` in `columnDef`

```
columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Sample data",
    field: "sampleNumber",
    valueFormatter: numberFormatter,
    width: 200
  }
];
...
numberFormatter(params){
    // params.data - full row data
    // params.value - cell value
    // here you can handle how certain cell data would be displayed on the grid
    return Number(params.value.toFixed(params.data.samplePrecision))
}
```

Here is a working [plnkr sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/StXsnWVfMW8ahUNkEbou)

[Official docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-setters/) for `Value Setters` & `Value Parsers`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example that should work using Angular 8:

```
columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'charge',
        headerName: 'Charge',
        valueFormatter: this.currencyFormatter,
        precision: 3
    }
]

currencyFormatter(params: any) {
  return params.value.toFixed(params.colDef.precision);
}
```